# Yii2: How to define textInput() with dynamic attribute names in a view file?

Tags: php, model, yii2

I have a function in my controller file that get the persons who lives in a city.

**My controller file:**

```
public function actionGetPersons($id_city)
{
    $model = Persons::find()->where(['id_city' => $id_city])->all();

    return $this->render('persons-city', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Then I have my model file that have to show a form with text inputs: one text input per persons and its **attribute name** have to be the **name of the person**.

**My view file:**

```
<?
foreach ($model as $person) {
    $form->field($person, $person->person_name)->textInput();
}
?>
```

**But the browser shows this error:**

> Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException Getting unknown
>   property: app\models\Persons::John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your view to be like this:

```
<?php
foreach ($model as $key=>$person) {
    echo $form->field($person, "[{$key}]person_name")->textInput(['value' => $person->person_name]);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

second param for field() method should be field name, not current field value

in your example:

```
<?
foreach ($model as $person) {
    $form->field($person, 'person_name')->textInput();
}
?>
```

docs: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-forms